# Does jquery function within a Template.contentBlock in MeteorJS?

Tags: jquery, meteor, fullcalendar

I'm using a Template.contentBlock in my layout and trying to call Fullcalendar onRendered.

**Layout**

```
<template name="layout">
{{#if appReady}}

<div class="container-fluid">
    {{>header}}
    {{>errors}}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            {{> sidebar}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            {{> Template.contentBlock}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{{else}}
{{>loading}}
{{/if}}
```

**Template**

```
Template.userAppointments.onRendered(function() {
  console.log('userAppointments rendered')
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar();
  $('.row').css("background-color","blue");
});
```

Console.log is displaying but neither the fullCalendar reference or changing the row are. This makes me think that jquery is somehow bricked in the Template.contentBlock.

Thanks in advance for your enlightenment.

Comment: What is printed by `console.log($)`?

Comment: @4castle ( selector, context ) {                                                                            // 70
  // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'               …

Comment: To have a reference to the template's jQuery object you need to explicitly use `this.$`. So this part of the code should work. Put a breakpoint in your `onRendered` function and try to see what `$('.row')` and `$('#calendar')` return. Pretty sure they aren't there (perhaps because `appReady` is false?).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I was using a pattern within the userAppointments template that checked if the subscriptions were ready.

**Helper**

```
Template.userAppointments.helpers({
  ready: function () {
    return Template.instance().subscriptionsReady();
  }
});
```

**Template**

```
<template name="userAppointments">
  {{#if ready}}
    ...
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

This pattern blocked jquery from running in an onRendered function for some reason.